# How to search-text binding with Durandal/Knockout Startkit?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Durandal Startkit template doesn't contains a implemented search (that is OK).
What maybe what it should has is a observable property and binding it.
I try to show you here is how to bind a search-text to this demo, but it search for the wrong value (old value).

Here the ViewModel: Shell.js (out of the box)

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app) {
    return {
        router: router,
        search: function() {
            app.showMessage('Search not yet implemented...');
        },
        activate: function () {
            router.map([
                { route: '', title:'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true },
                { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
            ]).buildNavigationModel();

            return router.activate();
        }
    };
});
```

I added the observable property: searchText, and modified the search function to display its 'value':

```
searchText: ko.observable(),
search: function() {
    app.showMessage('Search not yet implemented... Searching for: ' + this.searchText() );
},
```

and I bound it to the view: shell.html

```
<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" data-bind="value: searchText">
```

Something is not right, the value displayed in the search is the **old value**, not the current one. Apparently the search function is executed first and then the searchText's value is set/updated. But I am not sure.

How we can fix this problem? (to use the latest value during search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search method is wired with `data-bind="submit:search"` but KO by default listens to the `change` event on the inputs when using the `value` binding.

However when you hit enter and submit the search form your input's `change` event doesn't fire immediately so you see the "old" value.

You can fix this with using the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` (see [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)) so KO will update your `searchText` as soon as you type something in:

```
<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" 
       data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```